# Auto encoder and decoder on numerical data-set

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, cryptography, autoencoder

i am working on cryptography.The data set i am using is numerical data to resolve the dimensional reduction issue i want to apply auto encoder and decoder neural network. is it possible to apply Auto Encoder on numerical data set if yes then how?

Comment: could you add more details to the question?  I don't see how those tools/subjects fit together.  I'd recommend adding some code, as that's what stackoverflow is primarily about

Comment: @SamMason i am basically working on multi keyword ranked search over encrypted cloud data for multiple data owners. and the data set i am using is about academic  conference publications provided by IEEE xplore including 80,000 keywords 20,000 papers . to solve the dimensional reduction issue i want to apply auto encoder and decoder neural network i just want to ask is it possible to do so? because so far i just found the codes which is apply on image data sets.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can apply classical Autoencoders to numerical data. In its simplest form its just a matrix multiplication to a lower dimensional space and then a matrix multiplication to the original space and a L2-Loss based on the reconstruction and the input. You could start from there and add layers if your performance is insufficient.

Comment: i am basically working on multi keyword ranked search over encrypted cloud data for multiple data owners. and the data set i am using is about academic conference publications provided by IEEE xplore including 80,000 keywords 20,000 papers . to solve the dimensional reduction issue i want to apply auto encoder and decoder neural network i just want to ask is it possible to do so? because so far i just found the codes which is apply on image data sets.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoencoder uses numerical data.